# cascaded isset with different if's don't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

How do you set up multiple issets in cascade in a view?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-10 d-flex justify-content-center">
        @if (@isset($client_name))
        <h1>List of the overall tasks of the{{$client_name}}</h1> 
        @if (@isset($project_name_tasks))
        <h1>List of project tasks of {{$project_name_tasks}} </h1>
        @else
        <h1>List of project tasks</h1>
        @endif
        @endisset
    </div>
</div>
```

It does not work properly.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't put the isset inside the if statement. It's an if statement on its own.

Comment: so how can i fix the code?

Comment: `@if (@isset($client_name))` should be `@isset($client_name)`

Comment: `@if()` is shorthand for `<?php if (...) { ?>`, while `@isset()` is shorthand for `<?php if(isset(...)) }?>`, so your code `@if(@isset())` is basically `<?php if ( <?php if (isset(...) } ?> ) } ?>`, which, for obvious reasons, is invalid. `@if` and `@isset` are blade directives, helper code which both open new `<?php ... ?>` blocks, so nesting them is not going to work. `@if(isset(...))` or `@isset(...)` is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
@isset($client_name)
    <h1>List of the overall tasks of the{{$client_name}}</h1> 
    @isset($project_name_tasks)
        <h1>List of project tasks of {{$project_name_tasks}} </h1>
    @else
        <h1>List of project tasks</h1>
    @endisset
@endisset
```

because`@isset` is Blade directive, so no need to have extra `@if`.

Alternatively you can of course use `isset` function from PHP but then you don't need to prefix it with `@` so it should look like:

```
@if(isset($client_name))
    <h1>List of the overall tasks of the{{$client_name}}</h1> 
    @if(isset($project_name_tasks))
        <h1>List of project tasks of {{$project_name_tasks}} </h1>
    @else
        <h1>List of project tasks</h1>
    @endif
@endif
```

**--EDIT--**

If each isset is separate from each other you should just close condition earlier so:

```
@isset($client_name)
    <h1>List of the overall tasks of the{{$client_name}}</h1> 
@endisset
@isset($project_name_tasks)
   <h1>List of project tasks of {{$project_name_tasks}} </h1>
@else
  <h1>List of project tasks</h1>
@endisset
```

@endisset

Comment: I don't want this, each isset is separate from the other

Comment: that is, the first isset is separated with the second, as if there were two if in cascade

Comment: @Sarah See my updated anwer

Comment: is not working, because if I click on the button that redirects me to all the tasks I get the error **compact(): Undefined variable $client_name_tasks**, but this has nothing to do with it because I should print the last h1, that is the third

Comment: @Sarah So there is also another problem with this code

Comment: sorry, ```$project_name_tasks ```

Comment: @Sarah Ok, as you can see, the error is at **compact():** which is at your controller's end, not the blade file.

Comment: I have a little doubt .. $project_name_tasks is a collection, if I write @isset($ project_name_tasks) can this be the problem?

Comment: @Sarah It can be, the you should rather use `@if ($project_name_tasks->isNotEmpty())` instead

Comment: instead of isset you say?